# Recurring fuction which reruns if a certain condition is not met in a loop

Tags: javascript, recursion

I need UsernameFn recursively called (cc later lines) until the conditional loop within which it is called becomes untrue. If I place the loop outside UsernameFn function entirely, console says Username is undefined, even though the var Username is declared globally. What am I supposed to do?

[It says to add more detail. I have no more detail. It says to add more detail. I have no more detail. It says to add more detail. I have no more detail. It says to add more detail. I have no more detail. ]

```js
// dataset for username 

const alpha = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];
const num = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0'];
var counter = 0;
var Username;

// determine random length of the username
var UNlength = Math.random() * 11;
UNlength = UNlength.toFixed(0);

function UsernameFn() {
  // generate random nums as pickers
  var PickerN = Math.random() * 10;
  PickerN = PickerN.toFixed(0);
  var PickerA = Math.random() * 26;
  PickerA = PickerA.toFixed(0);
  var PickerG = Math.random() * 10;
  PickerG = PickerG.toFixed(0);

  // Pickers for the first character in "Username"
  var PickerUN = Math.random() * 10;
  PickerUN = PickerUN.toFixed(0);
  var PickerUA = Math.random() * 26;
  PickerUA = PickerUA.toFixed(0);
  var PickerUG = Math.random() * 10;
  PickerUG = PickerUG.toFixed(0);

  // choose randomly btw num and alpha. If Math.random 
  // is an even num, option = alpha. If odd num, option = num
  if (PickerG % 2 == 0) {
    var Chosen = num[PickerN];
  } else {
    var Chosen = alpha[PickerA];
  }

  if (PickerUG % 2 == 0) {
    var Username = num[PickerUN];
  } else {
    var Username = alpha[PickerUA];
  }

  //append each new choice to a string of previous choices
  //when string = UNlength <= 10 chosen ranbdomly above, stop recursion.
  // 'Username' declaration outside scope to allow loop access
  Username = String(Username) + String(Chosen);
  return Username;

  counter += 1;
  do {
    UsernameFn()
  } while (Username.length <= UNlength.length);
}
```

Comment: `return Username` ends the function before the loop.

Comment: You're also not assigning the result of the recursion to anything.

Comment: A recursive function needs a parameter. Otherwise, it will just return the same thing each time, not get closer to the base case.

Comment: If you were expecting to append to the global variable `Username`, that won't work because you declared it locally in the function.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for pointing out UNlength being already a number and that return terminates the function.         With the others: (i) I did declare var Username outside the function below the arrays. (ii) Why would I need to pass a parameter through the recurring function. The random Pickers have to change every the fn runs, result wouldn't be the same. (iii) The result of the recursion, like one before it, is coerced into a string and appended to previous results. I'm so so confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop should be outside the function. Then you need to concatenate the returned value to the `Username` variable.

Also, `UNlength.length` should just be `UNlength`.

```js
// dataset for username 

const alpha = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];
const num = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0'];
var counter = 0;
var Username = '';

// determine random length of the username
var UNlength = Math.random() * 11;
UNlength = UNlength.toFixed(0);

do {
  Username += UsernameFn();
  counter++;
} while (Username.length <= UNlength);

console.log(Username, counter);

function UsernameFn() {
  // generate random nums as pickers
  var PickerN = Math.random() * 10;
  PickerN = PickerN.toFixed(0);
  var PickerA = Math.random() * 26;
  PickerA = PickerA.toFixed(0);
  var PickerG = Math.random() * 10;
  PickerG = PickerG.toFixed(0);

  // Pickers for the first character in "Username"
  var PickerUN = Math.random() * 10;
  PickerUN = PickerUN.toFixed(0);
  var PickerUA = Math.random() * 26;
  PickerUA = PickerUA.toFixed(0);
  var PickerUG = Math.random() * 10;
  PickerUG = PickerUG.toFixed(0);

  // choose randomly btw num and alpha. If Math.random 
  // is an even num, option = alpha. If odd num, option = num
  if (PickerG % 2 == 0) {
    var Chosen = num[PickerN];
  } else {
    var Chosen = alpha[PickerA];
  }

  if (PickerUG % 2 == 0) {
    var Username = num[PickerUN];
  } else {
    var Username = alpha[PickerUA];
  }

  //append each new choice to a string of previous choices
  //when string = UNlength <= 10 chosen ranbdomly above, stop recursion.
  // 'Username' declaration outside scope to allow loop access
  Username = String(Username) + String(Chosen);
  return Username;
}
```